# Moderation analysis with longitudinal data?

Tags: interaction, panel-data

My data is a from a family-based weight loss intervention. One of the intervention goals is to reduce intake of energy-dense, low-nutrient foods (we call these RED foods). One major behavioral strategy we encourage is for families to improve their home food environment (i.e., reduce unhealthy foods and increase healthy foods available at home).

My hypothesis is that intake of RED foods (x) will predict weight (y), and that the home food environment (i.e., availability of RED foods at home) will moderate this relationship. I know that I could look at cross-sectional relationships at post-treatment, but I feel like I lose valuable temporal information.

Can anyone advise me on what type of analysis might be appropriate to answer this research question?

Comment: Since this is an interventional study, each of these components is a mediating variable and would not be adjusted in an intent-to-treat analysis. It sounds like this is a secondary analysis however. In either case, your conceptual model should consider whether the intervention should be adjusted as a possible confounding effect.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you mean "moderate" rather than "mediate"? To me, this sounds more like a mediator relationship: Not having unhealthy foods at home leads to less consumption which in turn leads to healthier weight:

Home environment --> Red food consumption --> weight loss

This is an indirect (mediated) relationship. You can test it by using path analysis, which can (and ideally should!) be used longitudinally. See:

Cole, D. A., & Maxwell, S. E. (2003). Testing mediational models with longitudinal data: Questions and tips in the use of structural equation modeling. *Journal of Abnormal Psychology, 112*, 558–577.

Maxwell, S. E., & Cole, D. A. (2007). Bias in cross-sectional analyses of longitudinal mediation. *Psychological Methods, 12*(1), 23–44. https://doi.org/10.1037/1082-989X.12.1.23

General references on mediation/moderation:

Baron, R. M., & Kenny, D. A. (1986). The moderator-mediator variable distinction in social psychological research: Conceptual, strategic and statistical considerations. *Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, 51*, 1173-1182.

Hayes, A. F. (2018). *Introduction to mediation, moderation, and conditional process analysis* (2nd ed.). New York: Guilford Press.

MacKinnon, D. P. (2008). *Introduction to statistical mediation analysis*. Routledge.

Shrout, P. E., & Bolger, N. (2002). Mediation in experimental and nonexperimental studies: New procedures and recommendations. *Psychological Methods, 7*, 422-445.